# Spring WebFlux URL Matching: differentiate between path and path variable

Tags: security, spring-webflux, api-gateway

I have 3 endpoints:

1. /api/dummy/{id}
2. /api/dummy/local
3. /api/dummy

I would like to allow access to #1 (with path variable) only and forbid for all others.

How to differentiate between path and path variable using AntPathMatcher?

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterAt(new OttWebFilter(myService), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.FIRST)
        .authorizeExchange()
        ....
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/dummy/{id:[a-z]+}")
        .authenticated()
        ....

   return http.build();
```

Comment: `/api/dummy` is just `/api/dummy/{id}` without a value, so i belive that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I would say thats not posible: endpoints 1 and 2 collide. If I call endpoint 2, server could think I'm calling endpoint 1 with `id = "local"`